# IE7 won't recognize this jquery code, ie8/9 ffox works fine

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm using this line in ie8 and works great :

```
$('#div_light tbody tr td').find('a:link').css('color', '#636466');
```

I can't get it working on ie7...anyone can explain me why?

Comment: How can we help without seeing the HTML and at least confirming the selector will work?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `:link` and replace it with `[href]`...

```
$('#div_light tbody tr td a[href]').css('color', '#636466');
```

(I also removed the redundant call to `find()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify it to this?

```
$('#div_light tbody td a').css('color', '#636466');
```

Perhaps could even be this (would have to see the HTML to know for sure):

```
$('#div_light tbody a').css('color', '#636466');
```